Proving the closure of $E$ is the intersection of all closed sets containing $E$
Let $E$ be a subset of a metric space $(X,d)$. Prove the following:
$$\overline E = \cap\{F \subseteq X:F\text{ is closed and }E \subseteq F\}.$$
I have to show what is given above.
This is my attempt below when considering the left hand side of the statement.
$\overline E = E\cup E'$,
$\overline E = \partial E\cup E^\circ$,
let $p\in\overline E\implies p\in \partial E$, $p\in E^\circ$.
Given $p \in E^\circ$, $S(p,r) \cap E \neq \varnothing$
OR
Given $p \in \partial E, S(p,r) \cap E \neq \varnothing $ and $S(p,r) \cap E^c \neq \phi$
$S_{\partial E}(p,r) - \text{is an open ball with center p and radius r which intersects both the set E and $E^c$ which is associated with boundary points} $
$S_{E^\circ}(p,r) - \text{is an open ball which intersects set E which is associated with},E^{\circ}$
$\implies S_{\partial E}(p,r) \subseteq E \subseteq F \subseteq X$ and $S_{E^\circ}(p,r) \subseteq E \subseteq F \subseteq X$

$E\ne\partial E\cup E'$.  $p\in\overline E\not\Rightarrow p\in \partial E$, $p\in E'$. Why "Given $p \in \partial E, S(p,r) \cap E \neq \varnothing $"? (What is $S(p,r)$? For which $r$ does this hold?)

@AnneBauval that was an error I adjusted it accordingly.

Still wrong. $\overline E\ne\partial E\cup E'$. And please define (in your post, not in comments) $S_{\partial E}(p,r)$ and $S_{E^\circ}(p,r) $.

I realized I put the set of limit points when I meant to put the set of interior points. sorry @AnneBauval.

This question is a duplicate of (e.g.) Show that the closure of $A$ is the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$, topology proof needed. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Closure+intersection+of+closed

@AnneBauval ty.
